# PartitionContext.RuntimeInformation is null in ServiceFabric EventProcessor

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-eventhub, service-fabric-stateful

I'm using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.ServiceFabricProcessor. Everything works, but PartitionContext.RuntimeInformation is null, even though I'm setting EnableReceiverRuntimeMetric to true.

Here is how it looks in my code:

```
    EventProcessorOptions options = new EventProcessorOptions();
    options.OnShutdown = OnShutdown;
    options.EnableReceiverRuntimeMetric = true;
    // tried this one as well, doesn't help
    //options.ClientReceiverOptions = new Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.ReceiverOptions()
    //{
    //    EnableReceiverRuntimeMetric = true 
    //};

        ServiceFabricProcessor processorService = new ServiceFabricProcessor(this.Context.ServiceName, this.Context.PartitionId, this.StateManager, this.Partition,
            new EventProcessor(), eventHubConnectionString, "$Default", options);
```

The code I commented is another way I tried to set it.

I'm running it on my local cluster.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: It might be better to raise an issue on github instead. https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-dotnet/issues

Comment: Good point. Will do.